# IronPython: AttributeError when calling `input()` with a parameter

Tags: python, visual-studio, ironpython

While calling the `input()` function without parameters (`x = input()`) works fine, calling `input()` with a parameter (`x = input("Type something")`) results in the following error:

> AttributeError: '_DebuggerOutput' has no attribute 'errors'.

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional details:**

- I'm using IronPython within Visual Studio 2010.
- The Python version I'm using is 3.2.3 (`print(sys.version))` outputs `3.2.3`).